# How to prevent site failure when mysql is down

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having an issue yesterday and today with my host (godaddy) who apparently is having trouble with a particular mysql server... in that it's completely out of commission for a few hours at a time.

Right now this causes my site to not load at all - showing this error:

```
[phpBB Debug] PHP Warning: in file /home/content/index.php on line 53: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'dbserver.com' (110)
Connect failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'dbserver.com' (110)
```

I'm guessing it's showing that because of this code I have:

```
// PREPARE DB CONNECTION
$mysqli = new mysqli("dbserver.com", "username", "password", "dbname");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

Which tells the php to stop altogether if mysql is down. So I suppose all I need to do is remove the "exit" function and I'm good to go?

I guess theoretically speaking, why is exit there by default in so many tutorials of how to connect to mysql? It kills the web site if the database is unavailable.

Just looking for thoughts from those who know much more than I please, thank you!

Comment: Will the rest of your site work at all if you can't connect to the database?

Comment: Remember not to post any sensitive data like username or password. Now go change them on your server.

Comment: Do you use any caching mechanism? like memcached?

Comment: @Jessica Actually the majority of it would not work right. :(

Comment: And don't forget to change your database password since you post it on a public site with thousands views a day!

Comment: @runelynx Well, so what would be the point of continuing on? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just bin this:

```
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
```

And replace it with a placeholder page instead to inform people that s**t happened and you'll be back later.

```
header('Location: error_db.php');
```

Comment: This won't stop the rest of the page code from execution and might not be what you want.

Comment: Should always have a `die();` or `exit();` after a header redirect.

Comment: As stated more than once above it is the common mistake to forget exit or die after header redirects. Anyone using this type of redirects should exit their currently running code if otherwise specifically intended.

Comment: @Madcoe: And if you read his existing code, you'll see that there is already an exit() following the line I suggested that he replaces. So where's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Displaying good and pretty error-messages to the user is often neglected by most programmers. This is because it can be a real pain in the ass to do the right way.

As Jassica commented, if your entire site function without the database-connection, you can just remove the `exit()` in your function and the site is good to go.

However, I guess the chances for a 100 % functional site without the database-connection are very small. What most sites to is to redirect the user to a 500-errorpage where they inform the user that something went wrong. Often provided contact-information so the right people can be notified too. Twitter does this, so does Facebook, Reddit and many more.

You can just do:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("dbserver.com", "username", "password", "table");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    header("Location: error500.html");
    exit();
}
```

Or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
function connect($u,$p,$db,$host) { 
   try { 
      $mysqli = new mysqli($host,$u,$p,$db); 
      $connected = true; 
   } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) { 
      throw $e; 
   } 
} 

try { 
  connect('username','password','database','host');  
} catch (Exception $e) { 
  echo $e->errorMessage(); 
}
```